# PITEST mutationCoverage is returning SocketException

Tags: maven, pitest

While running **clean test verify org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage**, getting the below exception.

```
PIT >> INFO : MINION : 
.pitest.testapi.execute.containers.UnContainer.execute(UnContainer.java:31)
-       at org.pitest.testapi.execute.Pitest.executeTests(Pitest.java:57)
-       at org.pitest.testapi.execute.Pitest.run(Pitest.java:48)
-       at org.pitest.coverage.execute.CoverageWorker.run(C

-Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
--      at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java
```

The micro service has many scenarios to execute, would like to know how this can be fixed. I see some details in http://pitest.org/faq/ refering under section
**PIT is taking forever to run**, but not sure, if there is a way to increase the thread count.

Comment: You should only use `mvn clean verify  org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`

Comment: @khmarbaise I still see the same issue removing "test" from the command.